# combine results from calling same function multiple times

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a function `func1(integer);`
it returns rows of: partid,qty
for example: 
`select * from func1(1);`

```
partid,qty
 10     50
 20     30
```

`select * from func1(2);`

```
partid,qty
 10     5
 20     30
 11     10
```

I need to write a function that calls func1 with array and group by the results.  `func2(integer[]);`

for example:
`select * from func2(array[1,2]);` should give:

```
partid,qty
 10     55
 20     60
 11     10
```

I wrote this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func2(listx integer[])
  RETURNS SETOF records_d AS
$BODY$
declare
    item integer;
begin
    foreach item in array listx loop
        select * from func1(item);

    end loop;
end;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

record_d is type (integer,integer)

This function doesn't work... I don't know how to combine the results from diffrent iterations of func1() and then return them.

Comment: Can you try creating global temp table and in functions insert wanted data into table, once you get what you want, you could just drop table?

Comment: i thought of that but was wondring if it's doable without using tables.

Comment: You could change the select in the foreach to `return query select * from func1(item)` and do the grouping in the outside query: `SELECT partid,sum(qty) as qty FROM func2(array[1,2]) GROUP BY partid`

Comment: Or, as they return same result set ... can you try going with Union?

Comment: @ Ctx i don't understand your solution. there is no outside of func2(). are you suggesting to write also func3()?

Comment: @Veljko89 there can be 1000 items in the array i'm sending to func2. how can union handle it?

Comment: Why don't you extend `func1()` to support an array? Can you show us the code of `func1()` and the query it does?

Comment: Either a func3() or in the query, which calls func2().

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  the code i'm writing is going to be used only once. func1() is an existing function in my DB. I wanted to simply use it. I thought there might be an easy solution but if there isn't i'll simpy copy func1() else where and edit it to support array.

Comment: what about a simple union? `select partid,sum(qty) from (select partid,qty from func1(2) union all select partid,qty from func1(1)) t group by partid`?

Comment: I don't know how many items are in listx. It can have also 1000 items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need another function for this, you can do that in a single SQL statement:

```
select f.partid, sum(f.qty)
from unnest(array[1,2]) i, func1(i) f
group by f.partid;
```

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/8b083/1

Comment: Whoa... this is certailny refined piece of code. :)

Answer (score 0):

As it is often with postgres, it have [RETURN NEXT](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html) clause, which is just what You want.

I think You will have to adjust the code to cast results of innes select into records_d type. But RETURN NEXT is what You want.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getAllFoo() RETURNS SETOF foo AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    r foo%rowtype;
BEGIN
    FOR r IN SELECT * FROM foo
    WHERE fooid > 0
    LOOP
        -- can do some processing here
        RETURN NEXT r; -- return current row of SELECT
    END LOOP;
    RETURN;
END
$BODY$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' ;
```